# Linked javadocs across multiple code repos

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a application whose various components are spread across about 100 git repos. They are all standalone maven projects (they have dependencies among themselves, of course), and I create a .war by bundling all of them for the application.

I want to create javadocs which are totally interlinked as much as possible (any mention of types from a different maven project is hyperlinked to its javadoc page). Maven javadoc plugin doesn't seem to allow that. Is there a maven config/any other way I can do this?

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: @fge Thanks. Seems like I can create another maven project which links all my existing maven generated javadocs. Thanks!

Comment: Note that my maven-(sna)fu is not really there, there may exist a more elegant solution than this one. As you can see I only link to external Javadoc sources.

Comment: @fge, that link seems to be broken.

Comment: @iX3 because it is indeed; I have dropped maven for months now. Removing...